Sizeof compound literal array producing side effects?

Does sizeof((int[]){1,2,3}) get evaluated at compile time? And is guaranteed by the standard.
Does the sizeof operand in this case produce side effects?

I am asking this question because with Tasking compiler this line results in warning "side effects of 'sizeof' operand are ignored".
I am wondering if this is a spurious warning or is there something to it.
I am trying to be compliant with MISRA rule 13.6 that states "The operand of the sizeof() operator should not contain any expression which has potential side affects".

As a possible workaround: Does it complain about sizeof(int[3]) ?

compound literals (the (int[]){1,2,3}) were introduced with C99. Maybe your compiler is interpreting the construct as something unusual? :-)

@TedLyngmo it does not complain. However I cannot use that as a workaround because I do not know the size of the array, hence why I am taking sizeof.

@pmg I don't think that would be the issue. Compiler is C99 compliant.

@user1806687 Re: "I do not know the size of the array" - Oh, is it a macro using __VA_ARGS__ or how else do you produce {1,2,3} ?

@TedLyngmo Similar yeah. Its #define LIST 1,2,3.

@TedLyngmo it does not matter as sizeof will be evaluated after preprocessing.

I guess that this warning is about creating the compound literal. Maybe your compiler is actually creating it.

@0___________ Yes, I was asking about __VA_ARGS__ because OP showed {1,2,3} but didn't know the size of the array, so I wondered how 1,2,3 ended up in there. :) I got the LIST thingy there so I'm good.



Does sizeof((int[]){1,2,3}) get evaluated at compile time? And is guaranteed by the standard.


The spec does not say, but probably so.  This is in any case not directly relevant to MISRA 13.6


Does the sizeof operand in this case produce side effects?


No, not as far as the spec is concerned. The expression (int[]){1,2,3} produces a value when evaluated, but the language spec does not describe any side effects (producing a value is not itself a side effect).  Contrast with i++, which both produces a value and has a side effect of modifying the stored value of i.
Note well that the operand is not evaluated at all, as other answers also observe, but that's the point of the MISRA rule.  It wants you to avoid sizeof() operands that would have side effects if evaluated, because it may be surprising that the operand isn't actually evaluated, and therefore the side effect does not occur.

I am asking this question because with Tasking compiler this line
results in warning "side effects of 'sizeof' operand are ignored".
I am wondering if this is a spurious warning or is there something to
it.

If MISRA is to be read as talking about side effects defined by the language spec then the warning is definitely spurious.
If MISRA were read as talking about side effects produced by a particular C implementation, including any not defined by the language spec, and if in your particular implementation, evaluating a compound literal did produce a side effect, then the warning would not technically be spurious.  But this seems a combination of a questionable reading and an unlikely behavior.  Moreover, even in this case, I'd say that the warning could probably be ignored without violating the spirit of the rule, because no one is going to be confused about a side effect not happening that they weren't expecting anyway.

The MISRA C spec refers to the C language formal definition of a side effect for sure.

There are no side effects here.
The only time the operand of the sizeof operator is evaluated is if the type is a variable length array.  The compound literal you've given is a fixed size array, so it won't be evaluated at run time.
This is documented in section 6.5.3.4p2 of the C standard regarding the sizeof operator:

If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the
operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
result is an integer constant


Yes, but I'm not sure this is responsive to the question, which is about whether the operand of the OP's particular sizeof expression has "potential" side effects.  The way the MISRA rule is phrased, I take it to be about whether the expression would have side effects if evaluated by itself as, say, a statement expression.  This answer thinks so, too.


1. Does sizeof((int[]){1,2,3}) get evaluated at compile time? And is guaranteed by the standard.

The sizeof operator is specified as (C11 6.5.3.4):

If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

And compound literals are explicitly not variable length arrays (VLA):

6.5.2.5 Compound literals
Constraints
The type name shall specify a complete object type or an array of unknown size, but not a variable length array type.

So yes, sizeof((int[]){1,2,3}) is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile-time, although the operand of sizeof is not evaluated for side effects.
Something like this wouldn't work: sizeof((int[]){i++}), the i++ would not get executed and the compiler only needs to know the type of i to know the size.


2. Does the sizeof operand in this case produce side effects?

No. Both the compiler and the MISRA C rule refers to the C language formal definition of a side effect here and not the general English language meaning. The formal definition of the term can be found in C11 5.1.2.3/2:

Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects

Your code doesn't do any of this so there are no side effects. Meaning that the Tasking warning is quite blunt, it ought to already know that there are no side effects in your code if it claims to be a C compiler.


Yes
No

There are two side-effects which sizeof, kind of, has.
The one which is obvious - padding. Your array of int does not have that issue, since size of int is by default match the size of addressed memory. So array of three ints is exactly equal to size of int multiplied by three.
The less known side effect is if you try to do sizeof(variable length array). Then the sizeof will (sometimes) defer to run-time:
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int foo = 100;
    double (*bar)[foo];
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(*bar));
    return 0;
}


I don't understand the part about padding being a possible side-effect when using sizeof. If I'm not the only one not understanding that, perhaps you could clarify that a bit.

Not a side effect per se, more like unexpected result. For me, even after 30+ years of C,  it is sometimes a surprise, what value sizeof() returned. Most often it happens if I have a struct within a struct and some of them are packed, some are not - one just can forget which one is packed for network, which one is unpacked for memory access... And as a result sizeof() returns something not expected...

Ok, so there really only one side-effect like the standard (and the other answer) mentions and that is that the sizeof operand will be evaluated at run-time if its a VLA?

Unrelated: By undoing my edit, you made your program have undefined behavior again. %ld is not the correct conversion specifier. %zu is. Both sizeof(type) and sizeof expression results in a size_t and the conversion specifier for size_t is zu.

I think you are missing that it this context (in the compiler message and the MISRA C rule both), side effect refers to the formal C language definition of side effect, not the general English language meaning. Your VLA example does not contain side effects but it is evaluated in run-time. A side effect would be something like sizeof(count++, *bar)); where count is updated. Another form of side effect would be accessing a volatile variable.
